# How to take a file as argument?

Tags: java

I realize that was not a very descriptive question, but I wasn't sure how else to state it..

I wrote an interpreter, Tiny_Int.java, for a made up language called "tiny". All I need to know is how to run the interpreter with a specified tiny file like so:

```
java Tiny_Int <Sample.tiny
```

It may be helpful to know I am using this to read the tiny file

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file); //file being the Sample.tiny
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are redirecting the file to the Java command, therefore you should read the content from standard input stream (`System.in`) using,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Use `br.readLine()` to read each line until it returns null.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be mixing up two concepts.  If you want to use shell redirection like this:

```
java Tiny_Int < Sample.tiny
```

Then the shell will push the contents of your file into `System.in`, and you don't need to explicitly load the file.  You just need to read it from `System.in`.

If, on the other hand, you want your program to take in an explicit argument saying which file you want to use, like this:

```
java Tiny_Int Sample.tiny
```

Then you'd want to look at the `String[]` argument to `main` to get the file to open.

Amazing how much difference a `<` can make!

Answer (score 2):

If you're expecting input from stdin, use `System.in`:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(System.in);
```

Note that if you read from stdin like this, then on Unix you can use a shebang line to make your `Sample.tiny` script executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/java Tiny_Int

print "hello"
```

When you run your script with `./Sample.tiny`, then the JVM will be run with the *rest* of your script on stdin.

Answer (score 0):

using command line arguments passed to your main method (String args[]).

more info: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

args[0] is your variable 'file'.